# Is it possible to create a loop where if i click on a picture box it will stop music, on click again play it

Tags: c#, loops, click, soundplayer

```cs
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SoundPlayer ssp = new SoundPlayer();
    ssp.Stop();
    pctmutesplash.Image = Properties.Resources.unmuteicon;  
}
```

Comment: No, loop is not what you want. And I doubt that creating a new SoundPlayer is what you want on each click, but I'm not sure there. I would keep areference to the player and learn how to check its state.

Answer (score 0):

surely, just check **if** music is playing and then stop when the button is clicked.
**if** there is no music playing, play it on the button click.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, i was wanting to do it specifically for a picture box as you can set the back colour to transparent so here is no border or set back colour... I ended up using a checkbox to get it working...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a loop where if i click on a picture box it
> will stop music, on click again play it.

Only partially the [`SoundPlayer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) is really limited and doesn't allow pausing, resuming or even muting songs. So we need to use `.Stop()` and .`Play()` each time we want to "pause" the track.

We can also use `.PlayLooping()` to ensure that the track always plays until we "forcefully" stop it with the button press.

**Example:**

```cs
// SoundPlayer with the Sound we want to Play
SoundPlayer ssp = new SoundPlayer();

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pctmutesplash.Image == Properties.Resources.unmuteicon) {
        ssp.PlayLooping();
        pctmutesplash.Image = Properties.Resources.muteicon;
    }
    else {
        ssp.Stop();
        pctmutesplash.Image = Properties.Resources.unmuteicon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply i really appreciate your time, when i use the code it stops the music but if i click it again it doesnt start again, i found a way for it to work but i had to use a check box so on click mutes it and if checked is false play it... I mainly want it for appearance purposes and pausing would be great but i have used soundplayer for everything cause i use .wav files

Comment: @RyanJM I edited so that you can use the Image to check if the song is already muted or not. If the answer solved your problem, please mark is as the correct answer so other people won't write answers even tough your problem is solved.